# Power query Excel Loop Date

Tags: excel, powerquery

i would like to loop this query directly in excel powerquery. I would like to loop the date found in the link: from the date in the link to today's date. the data must all be inserted into a query. how can i solve? thank you.

```
let
    Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.forebet.com/scripts/getrs.php?ln=it&tp=bts&in=2019-06-01&ord=0")),
    Data0 = Origine{0}[Data],
    Children = Data0{0}[Children],
    Children1 = Children{1}[Children],
    #"Rimosse colonne" = Table.RemoveColumns(Children1,{"Kind", "Name", "Children"}),
    #"Analizzato JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Rimosse colonne",{},Json.Document),
    Text = #"Analizzato JSON"{0}[Text],
    #"Conversione in tabella" = Table.FromList(Text, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Tabella Column1 espansa" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Conversione in tabella", "Column1", {"id", "host_id", "guest_id", "league_id", "Round", "Host_SC", "Guest_SC", "DATE", "DATE_BAH", "Host_SC_HT", "Guest_SC_HT", "comment", "match_preview", "host_stadium", "match_stadium", "HOST_NAME", "GUEST_NAME", "penalty_score", "extra_time_score", "goalsavg", "host_sc_pr", "guest_sc_pr", "weather_low", "weather_high", "weather_code", "short_tag", "Pred_gg", "Pred_no_gg", "odds_gg", "odds_gg_frac", "odds_gg_y", "odds_gg_n", "odds_gg_y_frac", "odds_gg_n_frac"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.host_id", "Column1.guest_id", "Column1.league_id", "Column1.Round", "Column1.Host_SC", "Column1.Guest_SC", "Column1.DATE", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Column1.Host_SC_HT", "Column1.Guest_SC_HT", "Column1.comment", "Column1.match_preview", "Column1.host_stadium", "Column1.match_stadium", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Riordinate colonne" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Tabella Column1 espansa",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.id", "Column1.host_id", "Column1.guest_id", "Column1.league_id", "Column1.Host_SC", "Column1.Guest_SC", "Column1.DATE", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Column1.Host_SC_HT", "Column1.Guest_SC_HT", "Column1.comment", "Column1.match_preview", "Column1.host_stadium", "Column1.match_stadium", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne",{"Column1.id", "Column1.host_id", "Column1.guest_id", "Column1.league_id"}),
    #"Merge di colonne" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Rimosse colonne1",{"Column1.Host_SC", "Column1.Guest_SC"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Sottoposto a merge"),
    #"Merge di colonne1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merge di colonne",{"Column1.Host_SC_HT", "Column1.Guest_SC_HT"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Sottoposto a merge.1"),
    #"Riordinate colonne1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Merge di colonne1",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.DATE", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Column1.match_preview", "Column1.host_stadium", "Column1.match_stadium", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne1",{"Column1.DATE"}),
    #"Riordinate colonne2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rimosse colonne2",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.match_preview", "Column1.host_stadium", "Column1.match_stadium", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne2",{"Column1.match_preview", "Column1.host_stadium", "Column1.match_stadium"}),
    #"Riordinate colonne3" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rimosse colonne3",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne4" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne3",{"Column1.penalty_score", "Column1.extra_time_score"}),
    #"Riordinate colonne4" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rimosse colonne4",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Column1.DATE_BAH", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Suddividi colonna in base al delimitatore" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Riordinate colonne4", "Column1.DATE_BAH", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.DATE_BAH.1", "Column1.DATE_BAH.2"}),
    #"Modificato tipo" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Suddividi colonna in base al delimitatore",{{"Column1.DATE_BAH.1", type date}, {"Column1.DATE_BAH.2", type time}}),
    #"Riordinate colonne5" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Modificato tipo",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Column1.DATE_BAH.1", "Column1.DATE_BAH.2", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne5" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne5",{"Column1.host_sc_pr", "Column1.guest_sc_pr"}),
    #"Riordinate colonne6" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rimosse colonne5",{"Column1.Round", "Column1.comment", "Column1.DATE_BAH.1", "Column1.DATE_BAH.2", "Column1.short_tag", "Column1.HOST_NAME", "Sottoposto a merge.1", "Sottoposto a merge", "Column1.GUEST_NAME", "Column1.Pred_gg", "Column1.Pred_no_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.goalsavg", "Column1.weather_low", "Column1.weather_high", "Column1.weather_code", "Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Rimosse colonne6" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Riordinate colonne6",{"Column1.odds_gg", "Column1.odds_gg_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_y_frac", "Column1.odds_gg_n_frac"}),
    #"Modificato tipo1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rimosse colonne6",{{"Column1.weather_low", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.weather_high", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.weather_code", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sostituito valore" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Modificato tipo1",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1.odds_gg_y", "Column1.odds_gg_n", "Column1.goalsavg"}),
    #"Modificato tipo2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sostituito valore",{{"Column1.odds_gg_y", type number}, {"Column1.odds_gg_n", type number}, {"Column1.goalsavg", type number}, {"Column1.Pred_gg", Percentage.Type}, {"Column1.Pred_no_gg", Percentage.Type}}),
    #"Divisa colonna" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Modificato tipo2", {{"Column1.Pred_gg", each _ / 100, Percentage.Type}}),
    #"Divisa colonna1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Divisa colonna", {{"Column1.Pred_no_gg", each _ / 100, Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Divisa colonna1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should let you get data for a given date range.

```
let
    // Should return JSON for a given date.
    getJsonForDate = (someDate as date) as text => 
        let
            httpResponse = Web.Contents(
                "https://www.forebet.com/scripts/getrs.php",
                [Query = [ln = "it", tp = "bts", in = Date.ToText(someDate, "YYYY-MM-DD"), order = "0"]]
            ),
            htmlParsed = Web.Page(httpResponse),
            extracted = htmlParsed{0}[Data]{0}[Children]{1}[Children]{0}[Text] // Will throw an error if path changes
        in extracted,
    // Should return JSON for a given date range.
    getJsonForDateRange = (inclusiveStart as date, inclusiveEnd as date) as table =>
        let
            dates = List.Dates(inclusiveStart, Duration.TotalDays(inclusiveEnd - inclusiveStart) + 1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
            jsonForDates = List.Transform(dates, each [date = _, json = getJsonForDate(_)]),
            toTable = Table.FromRecords(jsonForDates, type table [date = date, json = text])
        in toTable,
    // Should return a table representing the JSON passed in.
    parseJsonResponse = (someJson as text) as table => 
        let
            parsed = Json.Document(someJson),
            toTable = if parsed <> null then Table.FromRecords(parsed) else #table({}, {})
        in toTable,
    
    data = getJsonForDateRange(#date(2020, 8, 30), DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),
    parsed = Table.TransformColumns(data, {"json", parseJsonResponse, type table}),
    expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(parsed, "json", {"Round", "Host_SC", "Guest_SC", "DATE_BAH", "Host_SC_HT", "Guest_SC_HT", "comment", "HOST_NAME", "GUEST_NAME", "goalsavg", "weather_low", "weather_high", "weather_code", "short_tag", "Pred_gg", "Pred_no_gg", "odds_gg_frac", "odds_gg_y", "odds_gg_n"}),
    combineColumns = Table.CombineColumns(expanded, {"Host_SC", "Guest_SC"}, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None), "Sottoposto a merge"),
    combineColumnsAgain = Table.CombineColumns(combineColumns, {"Host_SC_HT", "Guest_SC_HT"}, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None), "Sottoposto a merge.1"),
    transformColumns = Table.TransformColumns(combineColumnsAgain, {
        {"DATE_BAH", each Date.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " ")), type date},
        {"weather_low", Number.From, Int64.Type},
        {"weather_high", Number.From, Int64.Type},
        {"weather_code", Number.From, Int64.Type},
        {"odds_gg_y", each Number.FromText(_, "en-US"), type number},
        {"odds_gg_n", each Number.FromText(_, "en-US"), type number},
        {"goalsavg", each Number.FromText(_, "en-US"), type number},
        {"Pred_gg", each Number.From(_, "en-US") / 100, Percentage.Type},
        {"Pred_no_gg", each Number.From(_, "en-US") / 100, Percentage.Type}
    })
in
    transformColumns
```

You can change the date range by changing this line in the code to whatever date range you need.

```
data = getJsonForDateRange(#date(2020, 8, 30), DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),
```

---

- It would be good to firstly check if the website (`www.forebet.com`) forbids scraping/bots in their terms of service/usage.
- Currently there's no delay implemented between each request. So if you specify a large date range, you might send a lot requests within a short space of time, which may adversely affect their server(s).
- The code, based on your question, assumes that the server's response will always be a HTML document with a particular structure. If the server (for whatever reason) returns a response that has a different structure, this code will throw an error.

Comment: Perfect it works, but at 19/08/2019 it get an error `[Expression.Error] 
The null value cannot be converted to the List type.`

Comment: @phil, have edited my answer. The amended code should now handle `null` responses by returning an empty table for that row. If you want, you can instead filter and exclude such rows (where the server returned no data).